# Indexing a table partition in MySql

Tags: mysql, indexing, partitioning

In my project I have a table with around 20 columns. We have partitioned table on column 'status'. For the sake of simplicity let's say there are two possible values of status "ERROR" and "SUCCESS". Hence we have two partitions say p1 and p2 for the table. What we want is to have different indexes on each of the partitions. For example, partition p1 needs to have index on column1 and column2 whereas partition p2 needs to have index on column 4 and column 5.

Is it possible to apply index on individual partition of table in MySql instead of applying indexes at table level? I am using Mysql 5.5. The reason I don't want to apply indexes at table level is that it will make all inserts slow. Insert in this table will have impact on response time to user. However updates happen via job, hence response time is not an issue.

Answer (score 0):

In MySQL indexing works at the table level, not the partition level.

From your question it seems like you need to be ready to do a lot of very fast queries that look like

```
 SELECT something WHERE status='ERROR' and col1='val' and col2='val'
```

and

```
 SELECT something WHERE status='SUCCESS' and col4='val' and col5='val'
```

Will you ever do an UPDATE that changes the value of the `status` column?  If not you could insert your SUCCESS and ERROR items into different tables, each indexed appropriately.  If you need to retrieve them together you can use a VIEW to do that.

Comment: Yes you have correctly understood the requirement. However status will be updated. As per your solution I will need to create two tables and first insert data in one table. When status gets updated, then delete data from first table and insert into another table. That does not seem to be best solution, but if we can not apply index at partition level then probably I dont have any other choice but to go with your solution. Thanks for your response

Comment: Is a delay of up to a minute permissible between the reception of new records and their insertion into this table (these tables)?  If so, you could insert them into a small holding table, then use an `event` that runs once per minute to batch-insert them. This would get the insert operation's timing out of your interaction-time budget.

Comment: Thanks for your response Ollie. I think I will have to use some of these custom solutions suggested by you since there is no inbuilt mechanism in MySql to handle this.